# Raspberry pi - cannot access any HTTPS site, iptables

Tags: port-forwarding, iptables, https, squid

I managed to configure Raspberry pi 2 and tp-link wn722n to act like an access point:

[image]

I have also installed squid on it, with port 3128. Everything works fine with HTTP sites, but I am unable to browse any HTTPS site. At first I was using those iptables rules to enable access to Internet for WiFi users:

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t nat -F

iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

Then I modified my iptables to forward port 80 to 3128:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
sudo iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -i wlan0 -p tcp --dport 3128
sudo iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 80
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 80
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -o wlan0 -p tcp --sport 80
```

When I try to do similar thing with port 443 nothing happens.

How should I modify iptables rules to get this to work?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Nice diagram. Your rules seem to redirect pretty much any traffic to port 3128/80. What is your actual goal here anyway? Why not just setup the squid as a regular proxy on your clients?

Comment: For now I just want every device that connects to Raspberry through WiFi (interface wlan0) to be able to visit any HTTPS website. I think I should do some port forwarding, like wlan0:443<--->eth0:443, I tried doing that by modifing those iptables for squid, but it seems not to work.

Comment: Well the obvious solution would be to just grant them general network access and not setup artificial rules like that. Hence the question what you're actually trying to do. Even if you are acting on port 80 what about 8080 or other non standard configurations? Am I correct to assume that you're trying to create a setup where a user is forced to use the squid proxy to connect to the internet?

Comment: Basically I want them to have full access to the internet, but route HTTP traffic through squid (which is also on raspberry). First code block gives me full access to the Internet, but nothing is going through squid, second block allows me to use squid, but users can't visit HTTPS sites (and probably more stuff, cause only port 80 is forwarded). I think that combining those two solutions would be the best

Comment: Yes but why not just set it up as a HTTP proxy within your client? It would be way easier than this if you don't want to force all your clients to use it. Or setup a automated proxy discovery option. Did you try to drop the last four rules? The last 4 rules are superfluous as you're accepting any connection anyway.

Comment: What's the point to configure all browsers on all devices, why I can do it on Raspberry? What is more it's more difficult to to this on e.g. android devices and I don't want anyone to set up proxy manually.

Comment: Software might not support it; it might not be HTTP; HTTP traffic is not bound to port 80. You're setting up a forced connection through a HTTP proxy for any traffic directed at port 80. At the same time you allow any other kind of traffic. Someone might simply use a tunnel to circumvent it. Using [PAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) or something similar and blocking access would be better - if you want to force someone to use the proxy. Does HTTP break with the PREROUTE rule? What's the `iptables -L` output if HTTPS doesn't work? What works without the PREROUTE rule?